# RMI from nodejs using NodeRMI module

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rmi

I am trying to connect to RMI service from nodejs using [nodermi modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodermi).
I used the same code from github ([here](https://github.com/bladepan/nodermi))
as well as nodermi-npm page. All I need is pass the token value (retrieved from request header) and send it to RMI for validating the token.

I am failing to connect to the RMI.

Here is piece of my code to connect to RMI:

```
            if (config.CAF.ENABLE) {
                console.log('CAF Enabled');
                var serverConf = {
                  host: 'server',
                  port: 1099
                };

                var clientConf = {
                  host: 'server',
                  port: 6500
                };

                nodermi.createRmiService(clientConf, function(err, rmiService) {
                    console.log('hello');
                    console.log('rmiService: ', rmiService);
                });

            }
```

> the console part is not getting executed.